# Using SQL Server Date datatype and C# DateTime to select records

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I have an `ActionResult` where I want to select records based on a date column in SQL Server. This date is in a column of type `Date`. I can't directly compare the dates since C# `DateTime` includes the time component and the `Date` datatype does not. Is there a nice way to do this?

```
public ActionResult AbsencesByDate(DateTime date)
{
        var absences = from attendance in db.Attendances
                          where attendance.Date == date
                          select new
                          {
                              returnedPersonID = attendance.PersonID,
                             FullName = attendance.Person.FName + " " + attendance.Person.LName,
                          };
        return Json(absences, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

where attendance.Date == date.Date

Comment: I think this is the easiest solution so I went with this.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the time part from your date parameter in your function.
Something like this :

```
public ActionResult AbsencesByDate(DateTime date)
{
    date = date.Date;
    var absences = from attendance in db.Attendances
                      where attendance.Date == date
                      select new
                      {
                          returnedPersonID = attendance.PersonID,
                         FullName = attendance.Person.FName + " " + attendance.Person.LName,
                      };
    return Json(absences, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```